# Booting Ubuntu 16.04 on Lenovo Ideapad 510

Tags: ubuntu, boot, usb, lenovo-laptop

I've managed it to install Ubuntu 16.04 on my brand new, no OS laptop Lenovo. I did it using USB (made with Rufus software). It did not go frictionless, but finally ended up with the happy message "Installation was successfull, please reset the comp".

However, when I reset it, take out the USB, it displays "No operating system" message. The OS seem to be installed, but not accessible.

What could this be?

Before making te successful installation, I've struggeled with EFI/Legacy, partitions and GRUB, apparently solving the problems one by one. Obviously something was not configured well.

Ideas?

Comment: Have tried found any solution?

Comment: Try this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141879/error-1962-no-operating-system-found-after-installing-12-04-lenovo-thinkcentre).

Comment: Actually I came from stackOverflow, I made a deep research there. Somebody suggested me to try here and I just made a question, no prev research. Sorry for that, will now take a look.

Comment: I've tried several options and not succeded :(
I feel like my only chance is to randomly guess the right combination of EFI/Legacy (BIOS setting AND Rufus boot USB), partition structure and GRUB options, in order to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it, in legacy mode and running boot repair afterwards.
I's not totally stable, but something is something.